# Accidentally ran `mkfs.ext4` on my `/boot` partition (fedora 36)

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, fedora, grub

I pulled a total amateur-hour move and ran `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2` on accident the other day while trying to troubleshoot a hosed retropi sdcard. `/dev/nvme0n1p2` was my `/boot` partition on my work computer and now I'm in scramble mode trying to figure out how to recover the system. Messed up thing is I totally knew better, my brain was totally fried at that moment and I wasn't thinking straight. Right now it drops me into the grub prompt as expected. I tried following the directions here to recover from a live cd (https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/) , but I still get dropped into a grub shell. Please help! I am currently backing up the critical files I still need in case I have to do a fresh install and lose everything. I thought that I had originally partitioned `/home` on its own partition but apparently I didn't.

My guess is this is something to do with the fact that `mkfs.ext4` changed the partition from vfat to ext4 on `/boot`. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here are the commands I tried while in the live fedora image

```
# modprobe dm-crypt
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 myvolume
# mount /dev/mapper/myvolume /mnt -o subvol=root
# mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount -o bind /run /mnt/run
# mount -o bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
# mount /dev/nvme0n1 /mnt/boot/efi
# chroot /mnt/
# dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-efi-* grub2-common
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
# sync && exit
# reboot
```

Comment: Besides grub, the `/boot` partition also contains the kernel. You should try reinstalling your kernel.